# Difference between HTML and DOM

Tags: html, dom

What is the difference between DOM and HTML?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

DOM is a model of a document with an associated API for manipulating it.

HTML is a markup language that lets you represent a certain kind of DOM in text.

Other kinds of DOMs can be expressed in other markup languages, for example RSS and Atom can be converted to a DOM and manipulated with the same API as an HTML or XHTML document (more or less anyway; there are some HTML specific DOM extensions).

Comment: can you give examples of dom api ??

Comment: What's the meaning of "model" ?

Comment: For those finding this anno 2020 here you can find the answer to @Amrit and vikramvi their questions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API and here a bit broader but relevant info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction

Answer (score 24):

The Document Object Model (DOM) is a language-independent model made up of objects representing the structure of a document.  HTML is *one* language for writing such documents.

Answer (score 22):

Well, if you look in things like firebug, you can also check out the "DOM". Then they usually mean the current state the HTML page is in. So if you, for example, have a html page and add a  tag with javascript.

The actual HTML of the page is still the same, but the "DOM" however has changed.

**Notice that this isn't the right definition of DOM, but I thought this might be what you meant.**

Answer (score 7):

[DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) is the tree model to represent [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML).

Comment: DOM: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_object_model

HTML: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML

Comment: But not only HTML!  Also, it doesn't really represent the HTML, but rather it represents the document to which the HTML has been parsed.

Comment: Thanks to all for the answers and your time

Answer (score 3):

The HTML of a page is a *string*, and the DOM of the page is what happens when you take that string and construct an *object* in the object-oriented programming sense of the term "object".  Creating that object is how JavaScript is able to interact with the page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model#JavaScript

> When a web page is loaded, the browser creates a Document Object Model of the page, which is an object oriented representation of an HTML document, that acts as an interface between JavaScript and the document itself and allows the creation of dynamic web pages.

Answer (score 0):

HTML/DOM : HTML is what comes back from the server in the answer request, and gets parsed
Whereas the DOM (Document Object Model) is what the browser builds with it and can be manipulated with JavaScript. This makes a huge difference if you miss an element from a web page.