# What is the javascript equivalent to jquery closest()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code, which is written in DOM API instead of jquery. I'm not sure why. It's inside the submit function for jquery form validation. I need to change the "parentNode" part so that instead of "parent" it is "closest." I'm no good with javascript. I tried my hand at converting this to jquery, but wasn't able to get that to work. Basically, if this were jquery, I'd need to change .parent() to .closest().

```
var summary = "";

$.each(element, function() { 
summary += "<li>" + this.element.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('label')[0].innerHTML.replace("\<span\>*\<\/span\>","") + "</li>"; 
});

summary = summary.replace(/\<li\>.+\<\/li\>\1/, "$1");

alert(summary);
```

Is this possible to do with javascript? Or, is there an easy way to convert this to jquery?

**UPDATE:** Here is a fiddle to help explain what I'm trying to accomplish. Basically, because I added a 'span' tag around one of the inputs, the 'p' tag is no longer the parent. As such, the parentNode is not finding the 'p' tag anymore.

**http://jsfiddle.net/9um8xt79/1/**

UPDATE 2 -- THE previous fiddle link was incorrect. The link above is the right one.

How can I modify to find the `<p>` tag regardless of whether it is the direct parent, or a grandparent?

Comment: "which is written in javascript instead of jquery" - this overdrove my oxymoron/contradiction detector.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using the wrong terminology. I realize jquery IS javascript. I'm not sure what you call the parentNode and getElementsByTagName parts.... XML?

Comment: @Lindsay the term you're looking for is native DOM API.

Comment: Thank you Fabricio. Is there any reason something like this would need to be written this way?

Comment: @Lindsay well, I assume you know [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) is the term to reference a software component's public operations, methods, types, input and output. And you're talking about [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) methods. So yep, DOM API.

Comment: @Lindsay BTW if you're not familiar with the DOM, see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4306870/1331430) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4800664).

Comment: Okay, I'm taking a look at your code -- looks like your code example is missing the part which sets `submitted` to `true` (I'm assuming it'd be in the `submitHandler` option). Also your regex doesn't make much sense to me -- it'd be good to know what you expect to be be `alert`ed.

Comment: Basically, you want to create a `<li>` element containing the label's text (minus `*`) for each field which fails the validation?

Comment: That is correct. The output should be <li>Label</li> It is working properly unless the p tag is not the direct parent of the input.

Comment: I also would suggest to avoid manipulating HTML strings when possible, see for example [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9um8xt79/3/)

Comment: Some clean up: http://jsfiddle.net/9um8xt79/4/

Comment: That's awesome. Thank you. It works if I append it as you said, but I need to wrap it in more HTML before I append it. (It's going into a modal dialog.) Here's a fiddle where I tried appending it, and you'll see it returns as an object? http://jsfiddle.net/9um8xt79/8/

Comment: I tried changing append to $(summary).html() instead of summary, but that only returned the first label.

Comment: oh sorry I had to be AFK. There are a couple options, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/9um8xt79/9/ or http://jsfiddle.net/9um8xt79/10/ but it is usually better to keep the separation of concerns (HTML outside of the JS): http://jsfiddle.net/9um8xt79/11/

Comment: Thank for sticking with it. The first two worked for my needs. If you'd like to move this to an answer I'm happy to mark it correct. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding closest element without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663941/finding-closest-element-without-jquery)

Answer (score 16):

Hello from the future (2019)! This is now directly possible with native DOM API in modern browsers (that is, not Internet Explorer):
[`Element.closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

So you can replace `jQuery(selector).closest` with `document.querySelector(selector).closest`.

Similarly, you should be able to eliminate other `jQuery` functions in your code such as `.children()` by using [native `.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) and `.addClass()` by using [`.classList.add()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

*See also*

- [YouMightNotNeedJquery.com](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)
- ["Native Equivalents of JQuery Methods - Part 1: Selecting DOM Elements"](https://codepen.io/Mobius1/post/native-equivalents-of-jquery-methods) 
  (links for other parts are at the bottom of this codepen)
- ["Native JavaScript Equivalents of jQuery Methods: the DOM and Forms"](https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-vs-raw-javascript-1-dom-forms/)

Comment: So how do you do it for an element variable instead of a selector string? EDIT: Seems like you can just call .closest() on a variable of type Element.

Comment: Element.closest() was already supported in 2017 by all major browsers.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen I think your comment is in agreement with my answer. [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) [had just been added to the DOM spec](https://github.com/whatwg/dom/commit/fd69cc7ed9251d12b1185b24e6f89d3f0481f39d) around the time this question was posted and nowadays [it's supported in >95% of browsers](https://caniuse.com/element-closest) (though IE requires a polyfill like `jQuery` or [`dom-closest`](https://github.com/necolas/dom-closest)).

Comment: Yes, I mentioned 2017 only to point out that Element.closest() was already supported by that time because the answer explicitly mentioned year 2019.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the javascript for the .closest property:

```
closest: function( selectors, context ) {
        var cur,
            i = 0,
            l = this.length,
            matched = [],
            pos = rneedsContext.test( selectors ) || typeof selectors !== "string" ?
                jQuery( selectors, context || this.context ) :
                0;

        for ( ; i < l; i++ ) {
            for ( cur = this[i]; cur && cur !== context; cur = cur.parentNode ) {
                // Always skip document fragments
                if ( cur.nodeType < 11 && (pos ?
                    pos.index(cur) > -1 :

                    // Don't pass non-elements to Sizzle
                    cur.nodeType === 1 &&
                        jQuery.find.matchesSelector(cur, selectors)) ) {

                    matched.push( cur );
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Whenever you're trying to figure out something is done in jQuery, you can always just take a look at the jQuery source and reverse engineer it to your scenario. Although there will be times when this won't work, the way your question is phrased, this is where I'd start.

Source: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I don't know how to apply this to my scenario. It sounds like I need to hire someone to revise that code for me.

Comment: Can you put together a js fiddle? I'm still unclear as to what you're trying to do.

Comment: In the fiddle, the label that is returned in the alert box for "Are you a U.S. Citizen" is incorrect because I wrapped the radio buttons for that question in a span tag. Therefore, the parentNode is now different from all the other questions. I need a way to write the code so that it doesn't matter if the input is wrapped or not.

Comment: Oh jeeeeez. I linked to the wrong fiddle! I'm moving way too fast. Sigh. HERE is the correct fiddle so you can see what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/9um8xt79/1/

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question carefully, I think you want something like

```
var summary = "";
$(element).each(function (id, ele) {
    summary +=  "<li>" + $(ele).closest("label").html().replace("\<span\>*\<\/span\>","") + "</li>";
});

summary = summary.replace(/\<li\>.+\<\/li\>\1/, "$1");
```

But I'm not sure what you're doing with this last line. First you add all the label-Elements as li-Elements and then you remove all those li-s? But I'm not really a RegExp profi so I might miss something here.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't write the original code, so I'm having trouble understanding why some choices were made as well. But I am CLEARLY not an expert in anything. This didn't work in my scenario, but I appreciate the suggestion and it gave me some things to think about.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm a bit late ;-) but here is a simple recursive function (calls it self with the `parentNode` to be analised) in plain old JS:

```
function closest( e, classname ) {
    if( hasClass( e, classname ) ) {
        //We found it!
        return e;
    }
    //console.error(e.parentNode.nodeName);
    if(e.parentNode.nodeName != 'BODY') //Last possibility! There's no parent behind!
        return e.parentNode && closest( e.parentNode, classname );

    //Didn't found it?
    return null;
}
```

**hasClass()** function (the equivalente to JQuery [`hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)) depends on the browser knowing `classList` - as in nowadays is almost the case.

But, anyway, here it goes for both older and (the so called) newer browsers:

```
var
    hasClass

;
if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
    hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
        return elem.classList.contains( c );
    };
}
else {
    hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
        return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
    };
}
```

As notice, for older browsers, we use a `RegExp` to string comparision.
Here it is (and, promisse, final stuff :-) ):

```
function classReg( className ) {
    return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
}
```

And that's it.
Now it's explained, if anyone uses the complete set of "tools", off course you have to code it down the inverse way (1st `classReg()`, then `hasClass` stuff and final our `closest()` queen).

Also, if you noticed, you gain here 2 equivalente JQuery *tools* (`closest()` and `hasClass()`) that you can use in multiple situations - as I use them for several years, now:
`hasClass( elem, 'my-class-to-check' )  //<= returns true || false`
`closest( elem, 'my-class-to-look-up' ) //<= returns the look-up obj || null`