# what are the similarities between DOM and raw source code of a website?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser, web

I know that DOM is different to raw source code of a website. DOM has javascript executed and embedded to the source code of the website. But i would like to know are there any components which always exist in both DOM code and raw source code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between HTML and DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110081/difference-between-html-and-dom)

Comment: i know the difference but need the similarities between the both.

Comment: There is no guarantee that there will be any similarity whatsoever.

Comment: thanks Alohci, this is what i am trying to find out. And people gave negative and different answers.

Answer (score 0):

The raw source code is what the browser uses to initially build up the document that it will hold in memory. That document in memory is the "Document Object Model" or the "DOM". Once the document is loaded into memory, it is possible that it will undergo changes that make it no longer identical to the initial document specified in the source code.

For example, when you run the code snippet below, you will see that the HTML and CSS cause the background of the page to be yellow, but when you click anywhere on the document, the background will become red. This demonstrates how the initial document comes from the source and then the document in memory can deviate from that.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(){
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
});
```

```css
body { background-color:yellow; }
```

```html
<p>click anywhere</p>
```